# Can I use "Welcome" to accept a suggestion?

Tags: vocabulary

Is it correct to say:

**He is very welcome to your suggestion**

Answer (score 1):

You can use *welcome* with suggestions, but I don't think your sentence works.

I would use *welcome* as a verb, like this:

> **He would welcome your suggestions**.

or:

> **He welcomes your suggestions**.

---

If you want to start the sentence with "He is..." an idiomatic way to say something quite similar would be:

> **He is *open* to your suggestions**.

The word *open* has many meanings, but one of them is often used in conjunction with "suggestions". For example, this definition is found on the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/open) entry for *open*:

> Willing to consider or deal with something: *open to suggestions*.

while [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/open_1#open_1__38) says:

> willing to consider many different possibilities
>   **be open to something**: *I have some ideas about where to go, but I’m open to suggestions*.

Answer (score 0):

When *welcome* is used as an adjective, it refers to the person or thing being "gladly received" ([source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/welcome?s=t)). In this case, it is the **suggestion** which is being received, not the person. So you can use welcome in this scenario, but it should be like:

> Your suggestion is very welcome to him.